# MongoDB balancer is not starting

Tags: mongodb, nosql, sharding

sh.status()

```
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("5dfa6c3cb121a735f9ad8f6e")
  }
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "s0",  "host" : "s0/localhost:37017,localhost:37018,localhost:37019",  "state" : 1 }
        {  "_id" : "s1",  "host" : "s1/localhost:47017,localhost:47018,localhost:47019",  "state" : 1 }
        {  "_id" : "s2",  "host" : "s2/localhost:57017,localhost:57018,localhost:57019",  "state" : 1 }
  active mongoses:
        "4.2.1" : 1
  autosplit:
        Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
                Balancer active window is set between 00:00 and 23:59 server local time
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
                No recent migrations
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "apple",  "primary" : "s2",  "partitioned" : true,  "version" : {  "uuid" : UUID("20431f1a-ddb1-4fac-887e-c4c5db01b211"),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
                apple.user
                        shard key: { "userId" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                undefined   undefined
                        too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print
        {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
                config.system.sessions
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                undefined   undefined
                        too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print
```

After starting balancing using **sh.startBalancer()** when I see the status the balancer running status is still false.

Is there anything need to configure while creating shard?

Answer (score 1):

> After starting balancing using sh.startBalancer() when I see the
> status the balancer running status is still false.

Balancer is a process which is responsible for evenly distributing chunks across a sharded cluster. *It is an automatic process*. By default, the balancer is enabled. It runs on the primary of the config server replica-set (mongos in 3.4 version or earlier).

The balancer runs only when needed. The balancer process checks the chunk distribution across the cluster and looks for certain migration thresholds. It identifies which shard has too many chunks in the cluster. If it detects an imbalance it starts a Balancer Round. It moves the chunks across shards in the cluster in an attempt to achieve an even data distribution.

From the `sh.status` output in the post, the balancer is enabled and not running.

> balancer:
>
> ```
>     Currently enabled:  yes
>
>     Currently running:  no
> ```

NOTE: The balancer will run automatically when even chunk distribution is needed.

You can manually start and stop the balancer any time; the commands `sh.startBalancer()` enable the balancer and `sh.stopBalancer()` disables the balancer temporarily when needed.

`sh.getBalancerState()` tells if the balancer is enabled and or not. `sh.enableBalancing()` does not start balancing. Rather, it allows balancing of a collection the next time the balancer runs.

Reference: See [Sharded Cluster Balancer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-balancer-administration/#sharded-cluster-balancer).